# Gunicorn reload fail with uvicorn worker class with docker-compose

Tags: docker, gunicorn, fastapi, uvicorn

I am running two services nginx and fastapi with gunicorn as server and uvicorn worker class as workers managed by gunicorn

**ISSUE**:

fastapi service is unable to reload changes on Hot Reload `--reload`

---

I have made sure that.

- Volume is set as `- .:/root/nlpengine`
- I have also checked using bash the changes within docker are visible
- using uvicorn as server reload works. `cmd: uvicorn --reload ...`

docker-compose.yaml

```
  nlpengine:
    build: 
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      args:
        options: --reload
    container_name: nlpengine
    working_dir: /root/nlpengine
    command: gunicorn 'app.api:app' --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 --timeout 120 -k uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker --workers 2 --threads=2 --worker-connections=100 --reload --reload-engine 'poll' --chdir /root/nlpengine
    volumes:
      - .:/root/nlpengine
    networks:
      my-network:
        aliases:
          - nlpengine-app
```

also getting this log which affirms the changes are visible inside the docker

`nlpengine    | [2022-09-18 15:24:17 +0000] [9] [INFO] Worker reloading: /root/nlpengine/app/api.py modified`

I am going to create an issue at gunicorn github repo as well. Meanwhile Please advise if anyone has experienced this issue before.

My first thoughts are that this might be due to gunicorn incompatibility with fastapi due to A/WSGI standards

Answer (score 3):

reason for this is —reload argument and —worker arguments are mutually exclusive

See [uvicorn](https://www.uvicorn.org/deployment/)

in order to use worker use your gunicorn in production and in local host use uvicorn